# Analysis of change in ordinal variable between groups

Tags: ordinal-data, paired-data, pre-post-comparison

A trial I was asked to analyze has examined 3 groups - intervention1, intervention2, and placebo, and compared before and after grades - an ordinal variable on a scale of 0 to 6.

How can one tell if there is a difference in an intervention?
I could treat the ordinal var as as interval and run Wilcoxon rank sum in each group - but that won't compare between group differences.
The options I see

1. Get the grade before-and-after difference, and use it in an ordinal logistic model - has an underlying assumption that differences between grades are equal, which they aren't
2. Treat the ordinal variable as continuous and run ANCOVA - violates model assumptions but acknowledges nature of matched data
   The 3 options I mentioned all look bad to me.
   Other, better ones?

Comment: How many participants do you have ? Subject to that, you could run a ordinal mixed effects model with random intercepts for participants

Comment: 20 in each of the 3 groups

Comment: Such as the clmm() R function from the [ordinal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf) package?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking (and you obviously have sufficient participants for random intercepts)

Comment: `as interval and run Wilcoxon rank sum` So, you think Wilcoxon test is not for ordinal data? Also, why Wilcoxon sum rank given your data is paired-samples?